# How to show that the restriction of $\pi$ to the subrepresentation $W$ factor through $G/N$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I am reading the [lecture notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/murnaghan/courses/mat1197/notes.pdf). On Page 16, Line 1, it is said that the restriction of $\pi$ to the subrepresentation $W$ factor through $G/N$. What does "factor through" mean? How to show that the restriction of $\pi$ to the subrepresentation $W$ factor through $G/N$? Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Factors" means that for the morphism $\pi|_W:G\to {\rm End}W$ there is a morphism $\alpha:G/N\to {\rm End}W$  such that $\pi=\alpha f$ where $f:G\to G/N$ is a canonical epimorphism.

Comment: thank you very much. But why there is a morphism $\alpha$ such that $\pi = \alpha f$?

Comment: Since $\pi(n)|W= id|_W$, i.e. $N<\ker\pi$.

Comment: @LJR You are welcome!